# Finding the maximum value of $\int_0^1 (f(x))^3 dx$, given certain conditions on $f(x)$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

How do I find the maximum value of $\int_0^1 (f(x))^3 dx$ given that

1. $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0$
2. $ -1 \leq f(x) \leq 1$
3. Domain of $f = \mathbb R$
4. $f$ is a real-valued function

For some values of $ x \space\epsilon \space (0,1)$, f(x) has to alternate between being positive and negative in a way that results in $(1)$.

But given that $|f(x)| \leq 1$, for positive $f(x)$, $(f(x))^3$ has to be lesser than $f(x)$ and vice-versa. So even though positive values of $f(x)$ are diminished when cubed, the negative values, on the other hand, increase in value. How do I use all of these ideas to move towards a solution?

The answers given in [Find maximum value of
$\int_{0}^{1}\left(f(x)\right)^3dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356361/find-maximum-value-of-int-01-leftfx-right3dx) seem out of reach to me. I am a stranger to Lebesgue integrals considering my calculus syllabus is restricted to high school calculus. I found this question in a practice question bank for a college entrance exam.

Comment: Just an observation: $\cos \pi x$ satisfies the given conditions..

Comment: @Safdar Yeah, I had the same function in mind, but obviously I still don't know whether it is a candidate for maximizing the integral.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Find maximum value of $\int_{0}^{1}\left(f(x)\right)^3dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356361/find-maximum-value-of-int-01-leftfx-right3dx)? $f^3 (x)$ actually means $f(f(f(x)))$, but I think you mean $(f(x))^3$ instead.

Comment: @TobyMak The answers given there seem out of reach to me. I am a stranger to Lebesgue integrals considering my calculus syllabus is restricted to high school calculus. I meant $(f(x))^3$

Comment: I see. None of the duplicates on this site are at the high school level, but this exact problem has been asked on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/problems/maximize-the-integral/?group=FMe7gNXpVJO2). Click on 'discuss solutions' and see if the first answer posted there makes sense. If it does, you can self-answer your own question.

Comment: @TobyMak I found this question in a practice question bank for a college entrance exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an elementary/high school level approach to the problem. Consider the expression $$\int_0^1 \left(f(x)-1\right){\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\right)}^2 \; \mathrm{d}x$$Since $f(x) \leq 1$, the expression above is less than or equal to $0$.  Expanding the integrand yields $$\int_0^1 f(x)^3-\frac{3}{4}f(x)-\frac{1}{4} \; \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 f(x)^3 \; \mathrm{d}x-\frac{3}{4}\int_0^1 f(x) \; \mathrm{d}x -\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \; \mathrm{d}x $$ $$= \int_0^1 f(x)^3 \; \mathrm{d}x -\frac{1}{4}$$
And because the expression equals zero when $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$,  $\frac{1}{4}$ is the maximum value.

Comment: This isn't the first time I have seen a solution which involves conjuring a seemingly random, auxiliary expression that simplifies the problem. But I've got to ask. How did you form this new expression?

Comment: Well, you want the expanded expression to involve $f(x)^3$, $f(x)$ because it equals 0, and any constants because that's easy to integrate; basically you just don't want any quadratic terms of $f(x)$. Also the integrand has to be less than $0$ to set up the inequality.