# Find the maximum value of $\int_0^1 (f(x))^3 dx$, under certain conditions on $f(x)$ and $\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IATqM.jpg)

I have gone through the solution here [Finding the maximum value of $\int_0^1 (f(x))^3 dx$, given certain conditions on $f(x)$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822324/finding-the-maximum-value-of-int-01-fx3-dx-given-certain-conditions-on) and satisfied with it but I am unable to find out the mistake of this solution available on the internet.[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onaAt.jpg)

Why is it wrong?

(Forgive me for using images. I am new here and not quite familiar with MathJax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct to write that $$\int_0^1(f(x))^3dx\leq 1$$ but that does not mean that the maximum value is 1. The point is that the maximum value must be *reached* by the function at some value of x.

For eg. $(x-1)^2+6\geq 2$ is a correct statement for all x, but the minimum value of the function is not 2, as you can observe.

Again, $\sin x\leq 55$ is a correct statement, but the maximum value of $\sin x$ is 1, not 55.

In other words, the global maxima (if finite) must be a ***least upper bound*** of the range set of the function. In the previous example, 55 is just an upper bound.

###### P.S.

Now, you may wonder what makes $\frac 14$ so special? Just like we found a lower number than 1, can’t we find a lower number than $\frac 14$? **NO**. That’s because the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -\frac12, & \text{$x\in [0,\frac23)$}\\ 1, & \text{$x\in [\frac23,1]$}\end{cases}$$ satisfies all the criteria and has $\displaystyle \int_0^1(f(x))^3dx=\frac14$.