# How do I make this 'intuitive' argument into a rigorous proof?

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals, proof-writing, integral-inequality

This question has been asked multiple times on this website, but I was not able to find a proper proof that went along this line of reasoning so I'm asking it again

> Find the maximum value of $\int_0^1(f(x))^3 dx$, if $|f(x)|\leq 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$, where $f$ is a real valued function.

$f(x)$ clearly cannot have the same sign everywhere in $(0,1)$. Let $a$ be the sum of the lengths of all intervals on which $f(x)\geq0$, and $A$ the set of all $x$ for which $f(x)\geq0$. This contributes to all the positive area of in $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Now $(f(x))^3\leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$ as $f(x)<1$ and $(f(x))^3 \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ for which $f<0$. For $f(x)>0$, we note that $f(x)=1$ is the only value  for which the cubing doesn't decrease the value. For $\int_0^1 f^3(x)$ to be maximum, we thus need $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ in $A$ (of course, letting the $+ve$ values everywhere got to max will mean the $-ve$ area needs to adjust for it, ie the $-ve$ area will also increase. But, in the space of all possible curves that could have the same area but $-ve$, there will be one that distributes it perfectly uniformly, ie a rectangle. And since the area is uniformly smeared, its value at any point will be less, thus, after cubing it will contribute less than the $+ve$ area which remains unchanged).

Collecting all of the x in A together (since integral is just a sum we can rearrange intervals) we can break $\int_0^1 f(x)$ into $\int_0^a f(x) + \int_a^1 f(x)$. Let value of $f(x)$ when its $<0 = -c$, the given condition of $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$ will then set the value of $c=\frac{a}{1-a}$. Doing the same with $(f(x))^3$, we find the area as a function of $a$, namely $a-c^3(1-a)$. We just need to find maxima of this function for $a$ in $(0,1)$ now, which can be done with simple calculus, and it comes out to be $1/4$ at $a=1/3$, which is the correct answer (though its totally possible to do this as is, I think calculation is easier with substituting $a=1-a$).

However, clearly my argument for why $f(x)=1$ for $x$ in $A$ is lacking for a formal proof. How can it be made rigorous? Or perhaps it is even wrong generally?

Edit: calling $b$ the measure of the negative part, to account for the case of $b$<$a$ (since then setting $f(x)=1$ for $x$ in $A$ could never satisfy $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$) we will instead have to find the maximum of $|f(x)|$, since each such function $f_i(x)$ satisfying our conditions and having $b$<$a$ would have a corresponding $-f_i(x)$ also satisfying our conditions which has $b$>$a$. However even then we will just have to break $|f(x)|$ into two cases, and the same exact logic will be used just twice.

Comment: I don't mean to be obnoxious, but presumably there is more the problem says about $f$ beyond it being a real-valued function. If not, $f$ might not even be (Riemann) integrable (e.g., take $f$ to be the restriction of the indicator function on the rationals to $[0, 1]$). So, what else do we know about $f$?

Comment: "Changes signs" and "sum of lengths of the intervals" implies $f$ is continuous. Is that a requirement?

Comment: You've got the order wrong when $f(x)<0.$ Then $f^3(x)\geq f(x).$

Comment: Saying that $f(x)=1$ must be true for all $x\in A$ ignores the condition that $\int f(x)\,dx=0.$ You can't just increase $f$ and still be within the bounds of the question.

Comment: @user1090793 nothing else was mentioned in the question (and neither in any of the multiple duplicates) so I assumed it has any other property for being riemann integrable

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what do you mean? The positive area will be compensated by the $x$ NOT in $A$, where the function will be $<0$

Comment: @Amadeus Often, the context will make some things clear. In a calculus class, if you have only defined Riemann integrals, then the assumption is that the function is Riemann integrable, rather than the broader Lebesque integrable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews " 'Changes signs' and "sum of lengths of the intervals" implies f is continuous. Is that a requirement?" I've edited the first line so that it doesn't seem to imply continuity, and for the second part, I didn't understand how that implies it is continuous. We're just collecting all $x$ for which f has the same sign. That should be possible even in a weird function like $f(x)=0$ when x is rational and $=1$ otherwise, right (of course there the length of the interval for $=0$ will be $=0$, I suppose)?

Comment: You can't necessarily increase the negative part to compensate for increasing the positive part. If $B$ is the negative part, and the total length (measure) of $B$ is less than the measure of $A,$ you can't set $f$ to be $1$ on $A$ and still satisfy $\int f(x)\,dx =0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Such a function would have a one to one correspondence with the negative of that function, for which its $B$ will become equal to your function's $A$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'll need to change my answer though, since now we will be finding maximum of $|f(x)|$ instead to 'include' both these functions in one. However we will be applying the exact same logic for it too, just twice now

Comment: "One to one correspondence" is probably the wrong term. There is a $1-1$ correspondence between $[0,1/1000000)$ and $[1/1000000,1].$ It's more complicated than a $1-1$ correspondence.

Answer (score 6):

Your observation that $f(x)^3 ≤ f(x)$ when $0 ≤ f(x) ≤ 1$ is good. A similar observation extends this idea to the entire range:

For all $y ≤ 1$, we have $y^3 ≤ y^3 + \frac14(1-y)(1 + 2y)^2 = \frac14 + \frac34y$.  Therefore,

$$\int_0^1 f(x)^3\,dx ≤ \frac14 + \frac34\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \frac14.$$

This is the maximum because it can be achieved by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac12 & \text{if $0 ≤ x < \frac23$,} \\
1 & \text{if $\frac23 ≤ x ≤ 1$}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, a similar approach had been used here- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822324/finding-the-maximum-value-of-int-01-fx3-dx-given-certain-conditions-on

Comment: I wanted to specifically see a way to solve it with my approach since it also gives the right answer but is too informal, so I'll wait to see if I can get another answer before accepting

Comment: @Amadeus The biggest problem with the approach you’ve written, even before trying to formalize it, is at “letting the +ve values everywhere got to max will mean the −ve area needs to adjust for it”: you’ve given no argument that such an adjustment won’t result in a net decrease of $∫_0^1 f(x)^3\,dx$. The argument you need to fill this hole is very similar to this one, and once you see it, you also see that it solves the problem completely by itself.

Comment: The argument is essentially that $x^3<x$ in $(0,1)$. Let's say $a=1/2$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ in it. Then $b=1/2$ and $c=-1$ to compensate, and thus even on cubing $f(x)$ the total area $=0$ as before. But now slowly pull the slider on the value of $a$ and start reducing it. The $+ve$ area to compensate for keeps decreasing, while the length of $b$ available to use for compensating keeps increasing. So $|c|$ will certainly decrease pretty fast.

Comment: Now since $x^3<x, |c|^3<|c|$, the area of $-ve$ part of $(f(x))^3 = b.|c|^3 < b.|c|$, or the area of $-ve$ part of $f(x)$, and as total area of $f(x)=0$ the total area of $(f(x))^3$ will always be $+ve$. Now note that for smaller values of $c$ the decrease in $c^3$ wrt to $c$ is also greater (basically from how the graph of $x-x^3$ behaves; there's a maximum at $x≈0.6$).

Comment: Hence now we need to find an optimum such that the absolute values of the areas are also big, and $b$ is big enough (ie $a$ is small enough) that $c$ has a small enough value such that the decrease in the $−ve$ area gained from cubing is efficient. The values of all these quantities arrived at in the answer is very consistent with these hand wavy arguments, and the final answer itself is correct too, so I feel quite sure that it's atleast not wrong.

Comment: Actually now that I typed it out it doesn't even feel all that unsatisfactory to me anymore haha

Comment: @Amadeus The hole I’m referring to happens *before* you can assume $f(x) = 1$ for $x ∈ A$—you’ve still given no justification for that assumption.

Comment: I gave the 'intuitive' argument that only in that case is the positive area not reduced, and subsequently here showed why the only problem that could occur- that the negative area will increase- is not necessarily any more of problem than some other case as value of $x^3$ doesn't increase very quickly except when it gets near $1$. So the $c^3$ from the case $f(x)=1$ in $A$ and case when $f(x)=0.7$ (say) wouldn't be very different ($f(x)=1$ or not we would always want the $-ve$ area to be a rectangle)

Comment: I know it is not wrong since the values I got match with the equality case of your solution.

Comment: what did you think of this? do you still think there is a 'hole'?